# Solution involving order in which babas move?

Tags: baba-is-you

I found a solution to the Further Fields level, but it only works half the time because it depends on the order in which the ("baba is move") babas act. Two babas are pushing on the same word at the same time and I need one to push it North before the other pushes it East.

It's easy enough to undo and swap the two babas if I get it wrong (it appears the order in which they act depends on the id of the baba and not on its position), but this seems somehow to violate the spirit of the game since it relies on hidden state.

Is there another intended solution that doesn't require the baba's to act in a particular order? Or is this intentional?

Answer (score 1):

The [Baba is You Wiki](https://babaiswiki.fandom.com/wiki/Further_Fields) lists several solutions that don't depend on the order in which the babas move. One such solution is:

> - You will be moving [image: KEKE], `KEKE IS PUSH`, and `YOU` across the [image: GRASS].
> - Push `KEKE IS YOU` so that it is aligned vertically with the empty void on the right side of the level.
> - Make `BABA IS PUSH` and push [image: BABA] in a vertical row such that it aligns with `KEKE IS YOU` vertically, except the bottom [image: BABA] is one tile to the left (see image below).
> - Put `PUSH` to the left of `YOU`
> - Make `BABA IS MOVE` and then quickly swap `PUSH` for `YOU` to make `KEKE IS PUSH`.
> - Let the [image: BABA]s push you/text across the level, and they will make `KEKE IS YOU` again when they run into the right wall.
> - Touch the [image: FLAG] to win.
>
> [image]

I was able to follow these instructions (although I had a bit of difficulty with timing) and win the level without any two babas ever trying to push the same bit of text.